# Using Select instead of Project with MongoDBDriver

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I wish to return a minimal version of a Book entity called BookInfo. I have a mongo collection of Books and I want to retrieve an list of BookInfo from that collection based on publisher id. The following are 2 implementations of the same repository method. One uses MongoDriver's Project method and the other convert IFindFluent to enumerable and then calls Select.

I wonder if there is any different between the two implementations the occurs behind the scenes (especially if one occurs on the DB side and on occures in memory):

1. Using Projection:

   ```
    public IEnumerable<BookInfo> GetPublisherBooks(Guid publisherId)
    {
        var collection = _dbContext.GetCollection<Book>(BOOKS_COLLECTION_NAME);

        var bookInfos = collection.Find(book => book.PublisherId == publisherId)
        .Project(book => new BookInfo()
        {
            Id = book.Id,
            Name = book.Name,
            Description = bok.Description
        });

        return bookInfos.ToEnumerable();
    }
   ```
2. Using `IEnumerable`'s `Select`:

   ```
    public IEnumerable<BookInfo> GetPublisherBooks(Guid publisherId)
    {
        var collection = _dbContext.GetCollection<Book>(BOOKS_COLLECTION_NAME);

        var bookInfos = collection.Find(book => book.PublisherId == publisherId)
        .ToEnumerable()
        .Select((Book book) =>
        {
            return new BookInfo()
            {
                Id = book.Id,
                Name = book.Name,
                Description = book.Description
            };
        });

        return bookInfos.ToEnumerable();
    }
   ```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try to frame the answer for this question by dividing it into parts. Yes, there is a difference between both the queries. Let me try to explain multiple factors that play role here.

The basic difference between both the queries is: `The first query will have the advantage of Projection`. It means the first query will just select the `Id, Name and Description` but second query will first get complete `book` object and then `select` at backend. If you are the one with relational DB background, then first query is equivalent to:

```
In RelationalDB:

Select Id, Name, Description from Book book where book.PublisherId == <<publisherId>>

In MongoDB:

db.BOOKS_COLLECTION_NAME.find({ "Book" : <<publisherId>> }, {"Id": 1, "Name": 1, "Description": 1});
```

As I understand, The question can be divided into two parts:

###### How does the projection helps us here.

- Projections are always helpful. As, we just select what is needed. So, in Big databases or the queries with large number of records, the `data transferred on the network will be limited and improves the performance` as, less data will be travelled over the network. And if you have a Index for those specific projections then it's a golden spoon.
- If you are using heavy queries without Projection, that is reading more amount of data then it leads to `increase in IO and degrades the performance`.
- For Queries without projection and `more number of active connections`: The MongoDB Driver will open up to maxPoolSize connections (default 100) to each replica set node. Additional attempts to acquire a connection will block on the pool up to maxPoolSize x waitQueueMultiple. waitQueueMultiple defaults to 5. Thus using the default values, up to 500 threads can block waiting for an available connection from a connection pool. If additional threads attempt to queue on the connection pool, a MongoWaitQueueFullException will be thrown.

###### And should we compare and than get the data, or should we get the data and than compare.

- It is the game of `indexes` that plays an important role here. `If you have indexes for the projections (fields) that you are comparing, then you can use the comparer on the DB side.`
- But for large documents, it's not a good practice to have index on all the fields. `For most common fields used in queries you can create indexes`, but for the queries which are rare or used just internally, you can give a thought before creating the index. `indexes increases the size of db and thus the cost`.
- So, `where we should compare: DB Side or Code Side`,

  --> Analyze your queries properly and have `indexes on most common queries` and use comparer for those field at DB side.
  --> and queries which are uncommon or don't have index, it's better to filter at your code side. `But be cautious, if your non-indexed query is heavy then it may time out.` So, for `non-indexed queries try to have concept of pagination in mongodb`.

Comment: Thank you su much for that elaborate answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ToQueryable().Where(...)` instead of `Find()` and leave out the `ToEnumerable()` the `Select(...)` gets mapped to a projection as well (some rules apply, see documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/csharp/current/fundamentals/linq/#-project)

Every call to `ToEnumerable()`, `ToList()` , etc. on a `MongoDbQueryable` triggers the translation of LINQ into a MongoDb query and its execution. Every LINQ operation afterwards is done in memory by the LINQ-to-Object implementation and not mapped to MongoDB.